# how to assign another class to a button class

Tags: css, class

I have a class for a button
    a class="btn2" href="#">REVIEW

And I have a class to get an inline pop-up window.
    a class="inline" href="#data2">

I would like to combine those two. In a way when the button is clicked the inline class is activated and an inline window appaers.

The inline class is yet working on a text line, but I like to have it work on a button.

Comment: Post the code of your classes

Comment: Really obscure your needs. Try to post some code example and put a bit more effort in writing you questions

Comment: I've uploaded a test site. [link] (http://hoddenbagh.nl/test_bibleopen/subjects_eBooks.html)
When you click on the text-link "what should I do to get to God", that is the second line under the first 4 book covers, you what I mean with the "inline class" The data for that is embedded in the same page.

I want that to work on the button.
BTW the download button doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood you want to set 2 classes on a single dom.

You can combine 2 classes by just putting a space in between

```
 <a class="inline btn2" href="#data2">
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. Probably it's not just to get #data but it isan inline class to get a pop up window with the review of the ebook I offer.

Comment: I've uploaded a test site. [link] (http://hoddenbagh.nl/test_bibleopen/subjects_eBooks.html)
When you click on the text-link "what should I do to get to God", that is the second line under the first 4 book covers, you what I mean with the "inline class" The data for that is embedded in the same page.

I want that to work on the button.